# Ajax update field database field in laravel blade template

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have a list of hotels in a select I want update the database base on the hotel selected if it update the field I want to alert it on the home page.
this is the ajax function

```
function showRoom($hotel_plan_id) {
var id = $hotel_plan_id;
if (id !== "") {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    url:'{{ route('home', '') }}/'+id,
    data:{_token:'{{ csrf_token() }}'},
    success:function(data){
       alert(data);
    },
    error: function (result) {
    alert("Error occur in the update()");
    }
  });


}
```

} 
my controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $hotel_plan_id)
{ 
    $hotel=plan_hotel::where('hotel_plan_id', $hotel_plan_id)->first();
    $hotel->hotel_name = $request->input('hotel_name');
    //$hotel ->room_name = $request->input('room_name');
    $hotel->save();
   // return redirect('/home')->with('success', 'price updated');

}
```

my route

```
Route::post('home/{hotel_plan_id}', 'HomeController@update')->name('home');
```

my select form

```
 {!! Form::select('hotel_name', array($item[4], $item[10]),'S', array('style'=>' Border:none; ', 'id' => 'hotel_id', 'onclick'=>"showRoom(this.value, $item[8])"));!!}
```

Comment: alert(id) what r u getting?

Answer (score 1):

You have error with ajax url and you dont also pass the value of hotel name.

Check this changes.

```
function showRoom($hotel_plan_id) {
var id = $hotel_plan_id;
if (id !== "") {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    url:'/home/' + id,
   data:{_token:'{{ csrf_token() }}', hotel_name: 'Your value here'},
  });
}
```

Comment: It is still not updating I changed the url.

Comment: I checked my value actually the value is empty is empty

Comment: because I used onclick because when you click you are not directly clicking to dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Please return json response

```
return response()->json();
```

Comment: this is the alert I put on my ajax to be returned when there is error alert("Error occur in the update()");

Answer (score 0):

You have to return json object like this

```
return response->json([
       'status'    =>  200,
       'result'    => true,
       'error'     => false,
       'data'      => $hotel
 ]);
```

Comment: It is still not updating.